# How can I solve this installation problem with fastavro on Mac?

Tags: macos, installation, conda, avro

I am trying to run in my Mac a Python program which requires working with `.avro` binary files.
Despite trying to install it by using: `pip install fastavro`, I always get an error message on the terminal that ends with the following lines:

```
...
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
      error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
 
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for fastavro
Failed to build fastavro
ERROR: Could not build wheels for fastavro, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I have updated conda to its latest version on my PC as well as updated pip as well.
Does anyone know how to solve this? I really need to run this program on Mac as soon as possible. For your information, I am able to install and use fastavro on Windows but not on Mac so this is likely to be a Mac-specific problem.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are working in a conda environment, why not install it with conda? I often find installations via conda much more convenient since it takes care of all non-Python dependencies as well.

So try uninstalling the package first with pip: `pip uninstall fastavro` and then installing it via conda: `conda install fastavro -c conda-forge`.

In case you are unfamiliar with the `-c conda-forge` flag, it tells conda to look for the package on the `conda-forge` channel which has almost all packages that are not available via the standard channels.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same error while trying to install from source.
Try installing a pre-compiled binary instead of building from source.

Below worked for me:

```bash
pip install fastavro --prefer-binary
```